# Como passar dinamicamente o name da input para o Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho a seguinte função em `jquery` no meu script `PHP`

```
$('.myinput').on('blur', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'gravadado.php',
        method: 'POST', // ou POST
        data: {
            q10600: this.value
        },
        success: function(resposta) {
            var div = document.querySelector('#divDestino');
            div.innerHTML = resposta;
        }
    });
});
```

Eu tenho várias inputs com a mesma classe (.myinput) mas no meu `jquery` aonde eu passo o nome estaticamente eu quero passar o nome da input que chamou o evento.

Ou seja, se foi a `input` com name q10630 que disparou o evento `Onblur` do `Jquery` eu quero passar na minha função `Jquery` o name q10630 mas se for a name da input q10700 que disparou o evento eu vou passar esse name 'q10700'. 
Não sei se ficou muito confuso isto. E também não sei se isto é possível de se fazer dessa maneira.

Ou se eu tenho de dar um nome de classe para cada input que eu tenho e criar um evento para cada uma dessas classes `Onblur` separadamente?!?
Pois eu tenho realmente muitas inputs no meu código `HTML`. Então ficaria centenas de eventos `onblur` se tiver de referenciar cada Input com um nome de classe diferente. Entende?

Answer (score 1):

Cria um **objeto** e passa chaves com o valor que desejas neste caso o nome do input
, e no *ajax* passas o **objeto** inteiro;

```
$('.myinput').on('blur', function(e) {

    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var data = {};
    data[name] = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'gravadado.php',
        method: 'POST', // ou POST
        data: data,
        success: function(resposta) {
            var div = document.querySelector('#divDestino');
            div.innerHTML = resposta;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Desculpe-me. Mas acho essa resposta meio vazia. O que faz este código? Testei e ele simplesmente passa o q10600 sempre.

Comment: resposta editada, assim dinamicamente passara a chave e o valor do input  chamado pelo blur

Comment: 100% Ninja, Resolvido.
Muito obrigado !

Comment: não tinha percebido a primeira vez, ainda bem que ficou resolvido! ^^